# Almost all integers contain the digit $3$

Tags: list-manipulation

How many number less than $k$ contain the digit $3$? 
For instance:

How many number contain the digit $3$ in the following list?

```
Table[n, {n, 33}]
```

$\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, \
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33\rbrace$

I tried:

```
numbers[k_] := Count[Table[n, {n, k}], 3]
```

but it doesn't work.

Then I want to find the limit

```
Limit[numbers[k]/k, k -> Infinity]
```

( [See  Numberphile video here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfEiJJGv4CE))

Comment: Please see [https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IntegerDigits` is the first that comes to mind. Let's do

```
int3c[k_] := Length @ Cases[IntegerDigits @ Range @ k, s_ /; MemberQ[s, 3] == True]
```

or slightly shorter

```
int3p[k_] := Length @ Cases[IntegerDigits @ Range @ k, _?(MemberQ[#, 3] &)]
```

or

```
int3f[k_] := Total @ Boole @ (Not @ FreeQ[#, 3] & /@ IntegerDigits @ Range @ k)
```

or

```
int3r[k_] := Count[IntegerDigits @ Range @ k //. {___, 3, ___} :> sth, sth]
```

All give of course the same output:

```
{int3c[33], int3p[33], int3f[33], int3r[33]}
```

> {7, 7, 7, 7}

Timing:

```
Table[int3c[i], {i, 1, 1000}]; // RepeatedTiming
Table[int3p[i], {i, 1, 1000}]; // RepeatedTiming
Table[int3f[i], {i, 1, 1000}]; // RepeatedTiming
Table[int3r[i], {i, 1, 1000}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.666, Null}
>
> {0.6255, Null}
>
> {0.768, Null}
>
> {0.8997, Null}

The winner is `int3p`.

---

**EDIT:** Using strings for this task is unreasonable, but just for fun:

```
ls = ToString /@ Range @ 33
```

Then the following give the same answer:

```
Count[#, True] & @ StringContainsQ[ls, ___ ~~ "3" ~~ ___]

Total @ Boole @ StringContainsQ[ls, ___ ~~ "3" ~~ ___]

Length @ Select[StringCases[ls, ___ ~~ "3" ~~ ___], Length @ # > 0 &]

Length @ Select[StringCases[ls, ___ ~~ "3" ~~ ___], UnsameQ[#, {}] &]

Length[StringCases[ls, ___ ~~ "3" ~~ ___] //. {} -> Nothing[]]
```

Comment: Or `Count[IntegerDigits@Range[k], a_ /; MemberQ[a, 3]]` or `CountsBy[IntegerDigits@Range[k], MemberQ[#, 3] &][True]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
int3[k_Integer] := Module[{fn}, fn = Boole@MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#], 3] &;
                     fn /@ Range[k] // Total]

int3[33]
(* 7 *)

Limit[int3[k]/k, k -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> Element[k, Integers]]

Limit[1 - (9/10)^k, k -> \[Infinity]]
(* 1 *)
```

---

I could be [mistaken](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicNumber.html), but I've heard that [three is a magic number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVfe6rdHRKI).

Comment: `Total @ Boole @ numbers3[33]`; might incorporate it into the def of `numbers3`. I'd do `int3[k_] := Total@Boole[MemberQ[#, 3] & /@ IntegerDigits@Range@k]`.

Comment: @corey979 thanks. I'd like to get rid of `Range` in the definition, in favor of something symbolic that plays nice with `Limit`.

Answer (score 3):

For the big numbers, here's a quick OpenCL implementation in case you want to use your GPU from Mathematica:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];
source = "
__kernel void count3(__global long* result, __global mint* amin, __global mint* bmax)
{
    const int id = get_global_id(0);
    const long a = amin[id];
    const long b = bmax[id];
    long sum = 0;
    for(long j = a; j <= b; ++j)
    {
        long x = j;
        while(x)
        {
            int r = x % 10;
            if(r == 3 ? 1 : 0)
            {           
                ++sum;
                break;
            }
            x = (x - r) / 10;
        }
    }
    result[id] = sum;
}

";
n = 10^10;
rangesize = 10^6;
ranges = NestWhileList[{#[[2]] + 1, Min[n, #[[2]] + rangesize]} &, {0, 0}, #[[2]] < n &];

fun = OpenCLFunctionLoad[source, 
   "count3", {{_Integer, "InputOutput"}, {_Integer, 
     "Input"}, {_Integer, "Input"}}, 64];

amin = ranges[[All, 1]];
bmax = ranges[[All, 2]];
Total[fun[ConstantArray[0, Length@ranges], amin, bmax], 2]
```

> 6513215599

Of course, there is a recurrence relation that gives you the number of numbers with $n$ digits or less that have at least one $3$, and if you're dealing with powers of 10, this is waaaayy more efficient than any brute force counting:

```
RecurrenceTable[{k[n + 1] == 9 k[n] + 10^n, k[1] == 1}, k, {n, 1, 30}]
```

> {1, 19, 271, 3439, 40951, 468559, 5217031, 56953279, 612579511, 
> 6513215599, 68618940391, 717570463519, 7458134171671, 77123207545039, 
> 794108867905351, 8146979811148159, 83322818300333431, 
> 849905364703000879, 8649148282327007911, 87842334540943071199, 
> 890581010868487640791, 9015229097816388767119, 
> 91137061880347498904071, 920233556923127490136639, 
> 9282102012308147411229751, 93538918110773326701067759, 
> 941850262996959940309609831, 9476652366972639462786488479, 
> 95289871302753755165078396311, 957608841724783796485705566799}

Using this with n=10^100, we can very clearly see the ratio is approaching 1.0:

```
N[9999734386011124125230661218677964220373170766547346605504025425038260
907509098697817005615300955999 / 10^100] 
(** 0.999973 **)
```

[See here for more](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/digit3.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

Shorter and faster than the accepted answer

```
Count[a_ /; MemberQ[a, 3]] @ IntegerDigits @ Range @ 33
```

7

Answer (score 2):

A faster version using `Compile`:

```
cf = Compile[{}, Length@Select[Range[33], MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#], 3] &]]

cf[]

7
```